# get app name from url in django

Tags: django, django-urls

I know how to get the url name with url resolve in django.

I want to treat all requests that come from a certain app similarly so I think I would do this by getting the app name from the url.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think it's a valid question. Cancelling -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting this by extracting the info out of the request.path

Answer (score 4):

path you would be a headache as you would have to apply a lot of splits. A better way to do this is:

`request.resolver_match`  which contains :

> {'app_name': '', '_func_path': 'app_name.views.ClassName', 'args': (),
>   'func': , 'url_name':
>   'url-for-class', 'namespace': '', 'kwargs': {}, 'view_name':
>   'name-for-class', 'app_names': [], 'namespaces': []}

Using    `request.resolver_match._func_path`  will fetch you app_name along with ClassName

Answer (score 0):

Views aren't really tied to an app in the same way models are.  They're really just python functions or classes (depending on FBV/CBV).  You could resolve the view and parse the module name to "guess" what app its from.

A better solution, if you're using class based views, is to create a common base view for all views in a given app that implements the functionality.

Here's the boilerplate:

```
class SpecificAppView(View):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Do something specific
        super(SpecificAppView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


class FirstView(SpecificAppView):
    pass


class AnotherView(SpecificAppView):
    pass
```

Comment: [This](https://github.com/appliedsec/djangular#using-django-templates-to-render-the-skeleton-of-the-app) is probably a good usecase for getting the app name out of the view?