# Context Processor for specific app only

Tags: python, django

```
'context_processors': [
    ...
    ...
    "publicfront.views.context_processors.add_event_url"
 ],
```

I added this context processor in settings.py and want to use only for a specific app. How could I achieve this?

Comment: you can't, the context processor is run for all requests

Comment: All right. Could you suggest any alternative approach to achieve this? @abidibo

Comment: You'll need to provide more details of what "this" is.

Comment: I am trying to add extra values to context so that I can use them in the templates. @DanielRoseman

Comment: the context processor func receives the request object, maybe you can use some if/else to determine which app is running and populate the returned dictionary accordingly, but it will allways run.

Comment: I know what context processors are... I wanted more information about what this particular one is doing, and why you want to run it for one app only, so that we can advise on different approaches - which might include template tags, shared base classes, etc.

Comment: I have achieved a solution for my problem. Thanks anyway. @DanielRoseman

Comment: @DanielRoseman is a good reason to restrict it to single app so that the pre-processing does not occur unnecessarily on all the other app templates that it is not needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The context processor is run for all requests.

If you need to mimic the functionality you speak about, then you could add some if/else conditions in the context processor function, which gets the request object as first argument, so you may determine which app is running and populate the returned dict accordingly

Comment: How would you determine which app is running from the request object?

Comment: @timbram see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261269/get-app-name-from-url-in-django

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers I've found so far are about adding a `context_processors` into the site's `settings.py`. But I want my application to be an independent development unit. On deployment, I don't want to perform on the site unnecessary adjustments that I could've included into the distribution. As it was already hinted above (by  Daniel Roseman), we can use custom tags ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags)):

```
# file `extras.py`
from django.template.defaultfilters import register
import platform

CURRENT_OS = platform.system()


@register.simple_tag
def current_os():
    return CURRENT_OS
```

That can be used like this:

```
{% load extras %}
. . .
<div>{% current_os %}</div>
```

As the `request` object is accessible in a template it may be processed with a custom filter ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)) like this:

```
# file `extras.py`
@register.filter
def my_filter(req):
    return req.GET.get('q')
```

Usage:

```
<div>You searched for '{{ request|my_filter }}'.</div>
```